# How to replace a numeric character enclosed by alphabetic characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a very, very long string containing words like `mushr0om`, `mong0lian`, `c0rn`, etc. I want to replace the `0`'s with `o`'s. I know that `input.replace('0', 'o')` may work, but in the very same string it also contains numbers like `70`, `100`, `1082`, and I don't want the `replace` method to affect them. Can I use regular expressions to do this?

Comment: Just use isNaN() to check if it is not a number

Comment: @amrit but as I have mentioned, they all exist in the same string like this: `mushr0om 70 mong0lian 100 1082`. Using `isNaN()` will affect the entire string.

Comment: Split a string into an array of substrings using str.split(" ") and then use  isNaN() to check if it is not a number and then replace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = "mushr0om 70 bl00m 102"

var cleanString = string.split(' ').map((word)=>{

  if(! /^\d+$/.test(word) ){ return word.replace(/0/g,'o')}
  
  return word

}).join(' ')

console.log(cleanString);
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check (previous and next character) for each character. If a character is a digit then check whether it's prev. or next character is a non digit. If any of the prev. or next character is  a non digit then replace.

- But if you have any substring like 'mongolia007' in your desired string set then the solution gets tricky. But for simple case above solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace all '0' which previous letter not a number and also the next letter not a number.

Split your string into a char array, then replace your desired char.

```
var str = 'Twas th0e ni0ght befo100re Xm305as...';
var char = str.split('');
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if((i==0 || char[i] != " ") && ! isNaN(char[i]) && isNaN(char[i+1]))
        char[i] = 'o';
    else if(isNaN(char[i-1]) && ! isNaN(char[i]) && (char[i] != " " || i+1 == str.length))
        char[i] = 'o';        
    else if(isNaN(char[i-1]) && ! isNaN(char[i]) && char[i] != " " && isNaN(char[i+1]))
        char[i] = 'o';

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + char[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you only need to replace the `0` occurring between characters and not the `0` in actual figure like `900`. Below regular expression creates three groups, two for characters and a zero sandwiched between them. Then we pick the first group (character before 0) using `$1` and second (after 0) with `$3`. The `0` is replaced with `o`.

```js
var str = "mushr0om, mong0lian, c0rn - 700 hello909";
var str1 = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(0)([a-zA-Z])/ig, "$1o$3");
document.getElementById("dvOne").innerText = str1;
```

```css
div {
  padding: 25px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dvOne">
</div>
```